# How do I disable caching on certain nodes in MVCSiteMapProvider?

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

I need to have a menu structure that changes depending on what page the user is currently viewing. Hence I need to disable caching for certain nodes as these may change for every request. How do I do this?

I have tried setting up the `DynamicNode` in the following way:

```
var dynamicNode = new DynamicNode()
{
    Title = title,
    Action = actionName,
    Controller = controllerName,
    RouteValues = routeValues,
    Attributes = attributes,
    ChangeFrequency = ChangeFrequency.Always,
    LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
    UpdatePriority = UpdatePriority.Automatic,
};
```

But that seems tohave no effect.

I have also set `cacheDuration="0"` in the *Web.config* file, no effect.

I've also set the following in the GetCacheDesctription of the DynamicNodeProvider

```
return new CacheDescription("GuideDynamicNodeProvider")
{
    AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now,
};
```

Also with no effect.

Am I using these settings incorrectly? The documentation on this aspect is rather lacking.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling caching for specific nodes is not supported. However, you can disable caching for the entire sitemap by setting the cache duration to `0`.

If what you are trying to do is refresh nodes when the data changes, you can use the [`SiteMapCacheReleaseAttribute`](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider#caching) or call `SiteMaps.ReleaseSiteMap()` when the data is updated.

On the other hand, if data is updated in your database from a source that is not under your control, you can implement `ICacheDependency` yourself to create a `SqlCacheDependency` class and then inject it using DI. Have a look at the [`RuntimeFileCacheDependency` class](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Caching/RuntimeFileCacheDependency.cs) to see how that can be done.

Note that the reason the `ChangeMonitor` is put into a list is so it will support the [`RuntimeCompositeCacheDependency`](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Caching/RuntimeCompositeCacheDependency.cs), which allows you to configure multiple cache dependencies for the same cache.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue. I'm explicitly calling `ReleaseSiteMap` but when I access from a remote computer, it looks like the cache is still there. What else can I check?

Comment: It is better if you call the SiteMapCacheReleaseAttribute on each of the (POST) action methods that update data. This ensures the call is made at the right time. Keep in mind that the same post that updates the data will typically also reload the cache, so you have to update the data first before making the call.

Comment: I set the `CacheDuration` to zero. Anyway, I think it has to do to my `VisibilityProvider`. Do you think there might be an issue with it? Please take a look at [the code](http://bit.ly/sitemapprovider), as a SiteMapProvider guru, I hope you find the issue right there.

Comment: Visibility providers are unaffected by the SiteMap cache (the nodes are always cached, a visibility provider will just specify whether or not it should be visible in the current context). So I am unsure what you hope to accomplish by reloading the cache. You could be having issues because you are using session state, which will carry the session data across browser instances.

Comment: BTW - setting `CacheDuration` to 0 has its own set of issues, and I don't recommend it.

Comment: It's bound to state by design; as you can see in my code, I'm setting the visibility based on current session's IP, and if it's an Israeli IP, I'm setting it to visible, so in order to reduce the mass of requests to the geoip server, I'm caching it on session state. Browsing the website from an anonymous server shows that the session value is actually correct, it looks like the visibility provider is not even called.

Comment: Oops! Got it! It was the `IsraelOnlyItemsPageKeys` that was tied up to the *Web.config* file, which wasn't deployed to the server! I do appreciate your effort and you've managed to teach another few things (the attribute is way kewl and smooth!)